# How can I return data from rows affected by an UPDATE statement using ODBC in C++ when an UPDATE trigger is active?

Tags: c++, sql-server, sql-update, odbc

I need to get the data in all the rows affected by an SQL UPDATE statement using ODBC. Historically I've done similar to the following:

```
// execute statement (assume handle created, parameters bound, etc.)
SQLExecDirect(hStmt, "UPDATE some_table SET some_field = ? OUTPUT inserted.* WHERE some_other_field = ?;", SQL_NTS);

// do something with each affected row
while (SQLFetch(hStmt) != SQL_NO_DATA) do_something();
```

And this works well, enough, except...

...the UPDATE statement with OUTPUT fails if there is an UPDATE trigger on `some_table`. I've read that this can be overcome by using `OUTPUT ... INTO` to put the results into a table variable. While this is straight-forward enough directly in SQL Server, I can't figure out how to do this through ODBC with C++ code.

How does one go about this?

Comment: You should be able to add the table declaration before the `UPDATE`, add the `OUTPUT...INTO` clause, and select from the table variable after the update.

Comment: Yep. That does it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The table variable is scoped to the current batch so you can execute a multi-statement batch as below.

1. add the table declaration before the `UPDATE`
2. add the `OUTPUT...INTO clause`
3. select from the table variable after the update to return result set